# Thread that executes every X number of days on c# - ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, multithreading

Basically what I have to do is create a thread that executes in a given number of days, which can change. The point is that an email should be sent periodically, and I'm looking for the best approach eventhough I know this is definitely not one of the best solutions but I **must** continue with this per requirements, hence I cannot use Windows Services, Windows Scheduler or anything similar. So the starting day for this email to be sent is when app starts, and then the next time should be after X days as specified in web.config. The problem is that I don't know how to keep track of that if the application stops (I can save the date of application start in database) but the number of days for the next execution may change. This is what I've done so far:

```
 private async Task<int> EmailScheduler()
    {
        var day = DateTime.Now.Day; //day when app starts
        while (true)
        {
            var currentTime = DateTime.Now;
            if (currentTime.Day == day)
            {
                SendEmail("mailto", "", "", "subject", EmailMessage());
                day += Int32.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["NumberOfDays"]); //next schedule
            }
            await Task.Delay((int)TimeSpan.FromDays(1).TotalMilliseconds); 
        }
    }
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: That is an egregious misuse of asp.net but you could probably make it work most of the time with a task scheduler like Hangfire if that is acceptable to whoever is creating requirements without understanding what they ask.

Comment: Can you talk us through why you aren't permitted to use Windows Services / Scheduler?

Comment: Another alternative is to use a third-party cron service to call a page at regular interval, and have the logic in that page

Comment: IIS has worker processes that execute the actual code. These worker processes are periodically killed by design, often when your process memory footprint exceeds some threshold. Certainly over a period of days, it is unrealistic to expect the worker process to not cycle. Are you open to the possibility of using a windows service whose behaviour can be controlled by your ASP.Net application? For example, an action in your Asp.net application needs to schedule such an email, so passes the detail to the windows service which marshals the email at the appropriate time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have no control over when your application pool restarts, and it will most certainly not be running for extended periods of time.

You could save the last execution date in a database, and periodically poll it to see if it has been longer than your given number of days.

The polling frequency would depend on your requirements.

This would somewhat approach sending a mail "every few days", but it would probably not be as accurate as a scheduled task.